# Uploading files django

Tags: django, file, uploading, download

I've been looking at this django snippet:
http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1036/#c3564

my code is:

```
    def handle_uploads(request, key):
        saved=[]

        upload_dir = settings.UPLOAD_PATH % request.user.username
        upload_full_path =os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, upload_dir)

        if not os.path.exists(upload_full_path):
            os.makedirs(upload_full_path)

        for key in keys:
            if key in request.FILES:
                upload = request.FILES[key]
                while os.path.exists(os.path.join(upload_full_path, upload.name)):
                    if (request.user.username not in upload.name) and (request.user.first_name not in upload.name):
                        upload.name = request.user.username + "_" + upload.name
                dest = open(os.path.join(upload_full_path, upload.name), 'wb')
                for chunk in upload.chunks():
                    dest.write(chunk)
                dest.close()
                saved.append((key, os.path.join(upload_dir, upload.name)) )
        return saved

    def upload_view(request):
        user = request.user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form =upload_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
                if form.is_valid():
                    saved_file = handle_uploads(request, ?)
```

in the example given, they seem to upload images. What should I put here if I want to upload ms word documents? Also in the example, they refer to a model called MyModel(), what would this model look like for msword documents. The way I want my site to work is that each user can view his/her documents that they uploaded. And then, if they need to, they can download these documents again. To attribute the documents to each user, should I add it in my expanded user_field class? And if I do, will the model referred to as "MyModel" in the example just be that expanded user field? Also, how do I set up file downloading? I didn't see anything in the docs about this.

Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think uploading a Word doc would be different from uploading a photo?

Answer (score 1):

Look at Django's documentation for [uploading files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/file-uploads/), the model's [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#filefield) field type, and the Django forms [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/fields/#filefield) field type.

You will probably want to define a model to represent your uploaded file:

```
#in your models file
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UploadedFile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='myfiles/')
```

Comment: Hmm, I'll try this out, in the meanwhile, what would I put in the question mark (the saved_file variable). In the example, they used ['thumbnail_images', 'banner_image']. But I'm not dealing with images, Would i just put, 'word_document' or something? What is the point of they 'key' field anyway?

Comment: The keys are used to pull the files from [Request.Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES), and as that link says, they correspond to whatever you named your input fields on your template. Note that snippet was contributed in 2008.

Comment: Does the UPLOAD_PATH and the 'upload_to' fields have to be the same? I ask this because my actual path changes depending on the user's username. And I don't know how to pass the username into the model class. (like request.user, except that only happens in the view.)

Comment: I don't know how you've defined `settings.UPLOAD_PATH` in your app, but what you should put in [upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) depends on what you have set your [MEDIA_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT) setting to.